# Can I conditionally remove the has_secure_password requirement when creating a second user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

In my app I have customised the Hartl sign-in/sign-out process to add the concept of Organization to a User account `User belongs_to Organization` and `Organization has_many Users`. The first time someone comes to sign up to my app they create both an Organization and the first user, who becomes Admin by default. The user is sent an email validation mail before they can sign into the site for the first time.

Once the Admin User is inside the site then they have the option to add more users to the App. Originally I just created new users and passed the Organization id inside a form, asking the admin user to email the new user their login details (and arbitrarily setting the password for this user for them). This isn't good enough for when I move to production so I now intend to create a new user for the organization without any password/validation, and when they click the email link to validate their email address I want to prompt them for their preferred password (and perform the validations).

From Railscast 40 I know it's possible to put `if: :some_test_for_user` statements into my `validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }` code, but how do I do this with the `has_secure_password` attribute?

Can anyone also help suggest a suitable condition to run as `some_test_for_user`? I was considering testing whether there were any Users already added to the organization, and if there's 0 users (i.e. new Organization) then validate the password, but if there's 1 or more users then permit Users to be saved to the database with no password present before they get their welcome email.

My code:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
default_scope { order('name ASC') }
belongs_to :organization
has_many :sales_opportunities
before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
before_destroy :allocate_sales_opportunities_to_admin
before_create :create_remember_token
validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(?:\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
has_secure_password
validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }
validates :organization, presence: true
before_create :confirmation_token

def send_password_reset
    generate_token(:password_reset_token)
    self.password_reset_sent_at = Time.zone.now
    save!(:validate => false)
    UserMailer.password_reset(self).deliver
end

def email_activate
    self.email_confirmed = true
    self.confirm_token = nil
    save!(:validate => false)
end

def increment_sign_in_count
    increment! :sign_in_count
end

def User.new_remember_token
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
end

def User.digest(token)
    Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(token.to_s)
end

def generate_token(column)
    begin
        self[column] = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
    end while User.exists?(column => self[column])
end

private

    def confirmation_token
        if self.confirm_token.blank?
            self.confirm_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64.to_s
        end
    end

    def create_remember_token
        self.remember_token = User.digest(User.new_remember_token)
    end

    def allocate_sales_opportunities_to_admin
        admin = self.organization.users.find_by(admin: :true)
        self.sales_opportunities.each do |sale|
            sale.update_attributes(user_id: admin.id)
        end
    end
end
```

Organization.rb:

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
validates :organization_name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }, uniqueness: true 
has_many :users, :inverse_of => :organization, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :users
after_create :set_admin

def users_for_form
 collection = users.where(organization_id: id)

 collection.any? ? collection : users.build
end

private   
 def set_admin
  if   self.users.count == 1
   self.users.first.update_attribute(:admin, true)
  else
   return true
  end
 end
end
```

From the User Controller (for adding new users when signed in as admin):

```
  def create 
   if signed_in?
    @organization = current_user.organization
    @user = @organization.users.new(user_params)

    respond_to do |format|
     if @user.save
        UserMailer.supplementary_user_confirmation(@user).deliver
        flash[:info] = "You successfully added a new user! They've been sent an email with details to confirm their account. Please ensure they follow up."
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
        format.js
     else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.js { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
     end
    end
  else
   @user = User.new(user_params)
  end
end
```

Relevant code from the Sessions Controller:

```
    def create
     user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
     if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
        if user.email_confirmed
        sign_in user
        user.increment_sign_in_count
        if user.sign_in_count == 1
            flash[:success] = "Thanks for signing up with MyApp! This is your user dashboard, follow the help tutorial to learn more."
        end
        redirect_back_or user
        else
            flash.now[:error] = "Please activate your account by following the instructions in the confirmation email you have been sent. Please check your spam filter to ensure you got the message."
            render 'new'
        end
    else flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
        render 'new'
    end
end
```

I'm pretty sure this is possible without creating a new Class of user for the site, and just changing the validations so I can pass just Username and Email across to the database for any users the admin creates, then prompting these newly minted users to enter their own password when they click my email-confirmation link. Can anyone help me work out how to do this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had the same issue in our app. Our solution was to generate a password for the users when new users are created using this: `before_validation :set_random_password, on: :create`

Then the users can select their own password when they activate their account. This way we do not have to do anything custom with the validations which might compromise security for active users.

## More of the code (as requested)

```
def set_random_password
  password = SecureRandom.base64(100)
end
```

Then we use perishable tokens for finding the user and allowing them to update their password. A perishable token is some secure string that updates every time the user is updated in the database. We use the same pattern for "forgot password emails".

We build a link looking like `/users/activate?token=#{user.token}` and send that in a email.

Then in the controller

```
def activate_user_form
  @user = User.find_by(token: params[:token])
  render :select_password_form
end

def activate_user
  @user = User.find_by(token: params[:token])
  @user.password = params[:password]
  @user.active = true
  if @user.save
    ...
end
```

Or something along those lines.

Comment: Thanks Albin, that sounds like a good solution to the issue. Could you share some of the code (e.g. how I could implement this). Would you do this for both the original user (who in my app becomes the Admin) as well as the subsequent users that the admin adds? How do you enable the user to update their password (as they won't know the random password when they go to sign in the first time)?

Comment: Thanks - I've marked this as the right answer as I'll implement this tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else comes across this issue, here's the final result that I've come up with based on Albin's answer above:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
default_scope { order('name ASC') }
belongs_to :organization
has_many :sales_opportunities
before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
before_destroy :allocate_sales_opportunities_to_admin
before_create :create_remember_token
validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(?:\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
has_secure_password
validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }
validates :organization, presence: true
before_create :confirmation_token
before_validation :set_random_password, on: :create

def set_random_password
    password = SecureRandom.base64(100)
end
```

In Organizations.rb:

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
validates :organization_name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }, uniqueness: true 
has_many :users, :inverse_of => :organization, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :users
after_create :set_admin
before_validation :set_random_password, on: :create

def set_random_password
 @user = self.users.first
 @user.password = SecureRandom.base64(100)
end

def users_for_form
 collection = users.where(organization_id: id)

 collection.any? ? collection : users.build
end
```

In my Users Controller I added:

```
  def activate_user_form
   @user = User.find_by_confirm_token(params[:id])
   flash[:success] = "Thanks for confirming your email. Please select a password to continue"
   render :select_password_form
 end

 def confirm_email
  @user = User.find_by_confirm_token(params[:id])
  @user.password = params[:password]
  if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
   @user.email_activate
   flash[:success] = "Thanks for signing up with My App! Your email is now confirmed. Please sign in to continue"
   redirect_to signin_url
  else
   render :select_password_form
  end
end
```

Organizations Controller

```
  def new
   @organization = Organization.new
   @organization.users.build
  end

def create
 @organization = Organization.new(organization_params)
 if @organization.save
  @user = @organization.users.first
  UserMailer.registration_confirmation(@user).deliver
  flash[:success] = "A confirmation email has been sent to the email address you supplied. Please confirm your email to continue."
  redirect_to root_url
 else
  render 'new'
 end
end
```

In my Organizations new view:

```
<%= form_for(@organization, :html => {:class => "form-horizontal"}) do |f| %> 
     <%= render 'shared/org_error_messages' %>
      <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :organization_name, :class => "col-md-4 control-label" %>
          <div class ="col-md-8">
          <%= f.text_field :organization_name, :placeholder => "Who do you work for?" %>
    </div>
</div>
    <%= f.fields_for :users, @organization.users_for_form do |user| %>
        <div class="form-group"> 
        <%= user.label :name, :class => "col-md-4 control-label" %>
        <div class ="col-md-8">
        <%= user.text_field :name, :placeholder => "What's your name?" %>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <%= user.label :email, :class => "col-md-4 control-label" %>
        <div class ="col-md-8">
        <%= user.text_field :email, :placeholder => "Email" %>
        </div>
 </div>
              <%= user.hidden_field :organization_id, input_html: {value: @organization.id} %>
          <% end %>
<%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-large btn-success" %>
<% end %>
```

in app/views/users/select_password_form.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for(@user, url: confirm_email_user_path, :html => {:class => "form-horizontal"}) do |f| %>
 <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>

 <div class="form-group">
 <%= f.label :password, :class => "col-md-4 control-label" %>
 <div class ="col-md-8">
    <%= f.password_field :password, :placeholder => "Enter password - minimum 6 characters" %>
 </div> 
 </div>

 <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirm password", :class => "col-md-4 control-label" %>
    <div class ="col-md-8">
     <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, :placeholder => "Repeat password" %>
     </div>
 </div>
 <%= f.submit "Save changes", class: "btn btn-large btn-success" %>
 <% end %>
```

And finally, in routes.rb:

```
  resources :users   do
   member do
    get :activate_user_form
    patch :confirm_email
  end
end
```

Now when a user signs in for the first time they receive their welcome email, use the link to confirm their account, and enter their password at that moment in time. Once signed in they become the admin user and can add others to the account. These users receive a slightly different email, but also come back to confirm the email address and set their own password.

Now all I need to solve is the ability to automatically sign them in when they select their own email address, as it seems a bit annoying for them to type a new password and then get asked to type it again to log in.